# In iOS 7, App using NavigationController with SplitviewController is not working as expected

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

Ref: After migrating from iOS 6 to iOS 7, our App is not working as expected with splitviewcontroller and navigationcontroller.

Sub: App flow which I have written in steps.

1. When selecting a row from PopOverController the MasterViewController we are passing our request to DetailViewController at
   "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" with delegation "[delegate SelectedViewController:self selectedrow:[rootTableContentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];"
2. In the DetailViewController we have implemented delgate method.

   -(void)SelectedViewController:(MasterViewController*)masterview  selectedrow:(NSString*)selectedRow

   {

   if([selectedRow isEqualToString:@"Labor"])

   ```
     {
            appdel.splitViewController.delegate=(id)laborViewController;
            [[appdel.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:laborViewController] animated:YES];
             ----
             ----
        }
   ```

   }

NOTE:
1. In iOS 6 when executed

```
[[appdel.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:laborViewController] animated:YES];
```

it is going to `viewdidload` and `viewwillappear` for `LaborViewController`, before excuting remaing code of the delegate method.

1. In iOS 7 it is executing total code from `-(void)SelectedViewController:(MasterViewController*)masterview  selectedrow:(NSString*)selectedRow` and going back to `MasterViewController` then it is calling "viewdidload" and "viewwillappear" for `LaborViewController`.

This is the problem in iOS 7, which I'm facing now.
`[[appdel.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:laborViewController] animated:YES];` is not firing `viewwilldisappear` or `viewwillappear` when executed.

Comment: If you can create a small demo project an upload it that would let others play with it.